# How to share URL of question marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, sharing

Given a question that is marked as a duplicate, when I grab the SO URL and share it with a co-worker they find it does not display the given question; *(the same happens if I paste the URL into another browser where I'm not logged in)*.  Instead, the URL automatically updates to the referenced duplicate.

Q: How can I share the original question?

*Reasons you may wish to share link: Discuss some answers or comments that was generated by the post, or to discuss the dup status itself.*

Comment: The URL is correct, but there's a redirect. See the linked question for why and how to work around it.

Comment: Thanks! Adding "?noredirect=1" did the job.